# rpmBUILD : rpmbuild display client side message or log

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, rpm-maven-plugin

> i have problem regarding the stderr and stdout message print on the
>   client console for specified costume message on specified costume
>   condition .i  want to put it on spec file or where?
>
> "like for example if i have build rpm xyz.rpm when after uninstall i
>   want to check if service of xyz is stop then and then it should be
>   uninstall otherwise give an error message and stop uninstall.i have
>   one more customization if i use -v then it should display otherwise
>   not.is it possible?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [rpm.org](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html) you can use the %preun script to run any normal shell commands prior to the uninstall occurring, so you could stop the service, or abort with an error.

Comment: ya that's right but excet syntax for error message and it print on verbose time only rpm -v .. otherwise not print.

Comment: go to this link my requirement .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698832/rpm-build-how-to-print-error-message-at-rpm-install-at-client